# How do I write a batch programe to copy a set of folders with same suffix and their files from a server to a client?

Tags: file, batch-file, xcopy

I want to write a batch program to copy some deeply nested folders with the same suffix in this case `100`,

It only copied all the folders but only one file in the top most folder (they are alphabetically arranged in the server) *100.bat was copied.

I want to copy all files in all folders with `name_of_folder100`.

Thanks for your Time.

This is my attempt:

```
@echo off

:: variables

 set hour=%time:~0,2%
 if "%hour:~0,1%"==" " set hour=0%time:~1,1%
 set 

 set drive= E:\PWD_BACKUP_%date:~10,4%_%date:~4,2%_%date:~7,2%_%hour%_%time:~3,2%

 set PWD_drive_100=E:\PWD_BACKUP_\PWD_100_%date:~10,4%_%date:~4,2%_%date:~7,2%_%hour%_%time:~3,2%

 set backupcmd=xcopy /s /c /d /e /h /i /r /y
 %backupcmd% "\\xx.xx.xx.xx\live_projects\PWD\*100"  %PWD_drive_100%
```

Answer (score 0):

It's normal to follow the `@echo off` line with `setlocal`. This makes sure that any variables altered or created in the batch file are not maintained in the `cmd` session's environment when the batch ends.

Use `set "var=value"` for setting string values - this avoids problems caused by trailing spaces. Don't assign a terminal `\`, Space or `"` - build pathnames from the elements - counterintuitively, it is likely to make the process easier. If the syntax `set var="value"` is used, then the quotes become part of the value assigned.

The `set drive=...` statement will **include** the space following the `=` in the value assigned to `drive`. This is probably of no consequence in the current situation, but may be significant for other batches.

Other than the last 2 lines of code, there is a great deal of date/time-manipulation going on. We have to rely on your local knowledge here as the date/time format is user-dependent.

The overall problem is that `*` cannot be used for directorynames. Logically, what you appear to want to copy from your description is `...e_projects\PWD\*100\*`, but that structure is not supported by `xcopy`.

So I'll restate the problem as "copy all directories that have a name ending `100`"

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
rem The following settings for the directories and filenames are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately includes spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "destdir=u:\your results"

FOR /f "delims=" %%e IN (
 'dir /b /s /ad "%sourcedir%\PWD\*" ^|findstr /e "100"'
 ) DO (
 SET "dirname=%%e"
 SET "dirname=!dirname:*\PWD\=!"
 ECHO XCOPY "%%e\*" "%destdir%\!dirname!\"

)

GOTO :EOF
```

**Always verify against a test directory before applying to real data.**

The `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` invokes `delayedexpansion` mode, where within a *code block* (parenthesised sequence of lines) `!var!` is the run-time value of `var` (as `var` is changed) and `%var%` is the value that `var` contained when the *code block* was parsed.

Documentation: [Stephan's DELAYEDEXPANSION link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2128947)

We then establish the source and destination directories. I've posted my test directories, you would need to edit them to suit your particular circumstances.

The `dir` command lists all directories (`/ad`) in basic form (`/b`) that is, name only - no size, date, etc. The `/s` extends the scan to subdirectories also.

The `dir` output is piped to `findstr` (the caret escapes the pipe to show that it is part of the command to be executed, not of the `for`) which filters the `dir` list for (directorynames) which `/e` end "100".

The `for/f` assigns each line of the result to `%%e`. The `delims=" ensures the entire line is assigned to` %%e`(in case`%%e` contains separators like <kbd>Space</kbd>)

`%%e` thus contains something like `U:\your files\PWD\sub 5\subsub 5\subsubsub\subsubsubsub100`, so we need to remove the part up to `\PWD\` to get the subdirectory name in a format suitable for the `xcopy` command. Batch cannot substring a `metavariable` like `%%e` directly, so we assign `%%e` to a user-variable `dirname` (which is therefore changing within the loop, so we need to use `!dirname!` to acess it's run-time value) and the following `set` removes all characters up to and including `\PWD\`. (See `set /?` from the prompt for documentation)

Then it's just a matter of performing the `xcopy`. Note that I've added an `echo` keyword to "disarm" the `xcopy` so that the `xcopy` command is merely listed to the console instead of being executed. Once you've verified that the command is correct, remove that `echo` to actually execute the `xcopy`.

The destination of the `xcopy` is </kbd> which tells `xcopy` that the destination is a directory, and to create it if it does not exist.

Add `>nul` to the `xcopy` command to suppress the report  if you want.